# Async TCP Server in .NET Compact framework

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, compact-framework

I'm writing asynchronous TCP Server in .net compact framework 3.5(console app), i used socket class only as TcpListener not supported .netCF. i used the same server code as given in msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.90).aspx). but after 2/3 days my system hangs, my system is ARM device with 64 MB RAM. what may be the possible cause. I didn't get such problem in Synchronous TCP Server.
Here is my code.

```
    public void StartListening()
    {
        try
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8001);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(4);

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
                    listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);

                    // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                    allDone.WaitOne();
                }
                catch (Exception pEx)
                {
                    _serverLog.WriteFile(pEx);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception pEx)
        {
            _serverLog.WriteFile(pEx);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ar"></param>
    public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        allDone.Set();

        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        //listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);

        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);

        //listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        string localIP = handler.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
        var _port = localIP.Split(':');
        string _ip = _port[0] + ":" + _port[1];

        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
            _receivedData.Enqueue(state.sb.ToString());

            Send(handler, " - ACK - Data Received.");

            //ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ProcessData), _ip);
            this.ProcessData(_ip);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="handler"></param>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    private void Send(Socket handler, String data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ar"></param>
    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception pEx)
        {
            _serverLog.WriteFile(pEx);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can be a little bit more concrete about 'system hangs': Does the whole device hang, is your application blocked, does it stop accepting connection requests or what are the symptoms? Have you traces the memory consumption / cpu load etc. of your application / of the system?

Comment: Hi Roland, System hangs means only applications will block, not OS. Yes it will stop accepting connections. And we traced memory usage, it increases gradually and CPU load also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is in a part you haven't posted here, but I can't see anywhere some code where you empty the StringBuffer `state.sb` or the Queue `_receivedData` (just assuming the types by Name/Method). Filling this two ressources can bring your system to hang as at some point there is no more memory...

Comment: Hi Roland, I'm Dequeuing _receivedData Queue in another method. and every time i'm creating new StateObject, so StringBuffer state.sb will set to null.